# Importance of adding detail from links: Problem with UC Davis ChemWiki website

Tags: discussion

Not sure why, but I am seeing some company, completely unrelated to the ChemWiki load everytime I try to go onto ChemWiki.

Just something to be aware of when answering questions and attributing information back to the link. If the website goes awry for any reason (whether temporarily or permanently), then it is always good to have a brief summary or quote of the pertinent information that you are including.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/ChemWiki/posts/10155843883630245

Comment: I see it too. It looks like the landing site for a web hosting service... Which is odd, because you would think that chemwiki.ucdavis.edu was actually hosted at UC Davis. Unless all that sits at that IP is a DNS redirect to an outside-hosted site, which seems like all kinds of bad practice!

Comment: @Ben It says, that it is 'powered by mindtouch'. I am not so sure what this says about the wiki though...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UC Davis Chem Wiki is back!

This meta post should hang around as cautionary tale.

Comment: I rather think about it as a monument. =)